# What breaks my whois on OS X?

Tags: macos, mac, networking, osx-lion, whois

For some reason whois does not seem to work on my machine:

```
whois heise.de
whois: connect(): Connection refused
whois google.com
whois: connect(): Connection refused
whois cia.gov
whois: connect(): Connection refused
whois wikipedia.org
whois: connect(): Connection refused
```

As you can see the problem persists for different TLDs so it does not seem to be just a broken whois server.

I get the same results using each /usr/bin/whois or Network Utility.

For testing I disabled Little Snitch as well as the Apple Firewall.

Other networking tools like ping, nslookup etc. work fine.

Any other ideas?

Comment: Sounds like a network connection issue rather than a `whois` issue. Is your connection up and going?

Comment: yeah everything fine icmp (ping) and dns (nslookup) as well as normal http usage seem fine

Comment: Did it work before?

Comment: I think it did.

Answer (score 0):

Probably your ISP is firewalling outbound port 43.  As a workaround, find a web-based whois service, or a proxy which will allow you to use a different, unblocked outbound port and have it rerouted to port 43 at the destination.